# how to use flutter dio connect-type multipart?

Tags: flutter, content-type, dio

my code here

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
    String fileName = event.file!.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file":
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(event.file!.path, filename: fileName),
    });
    try {
      var response = await dio.post(
        "url",
        data: formData,
        options: new Options(
          contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            headers: {
              "token": await getToken(),
              // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }),
        // headers: {"token": "test:1234"}),
      );
    }
    catch (e){
      print(e);
    }
```

my error version 1

```
error type. DioErrorType.other
error : SocketException : OS Error Connection refused,errorno=61
```

and
my error version 2

```
error type. DioErrorType.response
error : Http status error[400]
```

my requestOptions here

```
method = "POST"
_defaultContentType = "multipart/form-data"
```

How can I hand over the file to the server? The problem I think is that the content-type is not suitable, so there seems to be an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar implementation. I also use Dio, though in my code, I have it abstracted away with `_api`.

```
Future<Response> uploadLogo({@required File file}) async {
  String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({"file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename:fileName) });
  return await _api.post(url: url, data: formData);
}
```

Note that I don't even set the content type. I suspect that Dio looks at the type of object in the `data` parameter, and handles the appropriate headers/encoding under the hood.

Also, if you have having the content-type set to something unexpected, I'd recommend checking if you are using any `RequestInterceptor`'s. I was, and had to write an exception, because I was setting it correctectly, by my `RequestInterceptor` was overriding it, (because all of my other endpoints wanted JSON):

```
class RequestInterceptor extends InterceptorsWrapper {

  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, handler) {
    if(!options.headers.containsKey('content-type')) {
      options.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    }
    // ...
    super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

}
```

Comment: Even if I use the same or similar method, my header always starts with 'content-type application~~'.

Comment: Do you happen to be using a `RequestInterceptor` to set the header globally? I did, and ended up having to write an exception specifically for the file uploads. 
I can't format the code well enough in the comment box, so I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. It didn't work because I set the wrong key. The problem is solved now.